# How to get separate sums per each separate column by Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I want to get sums of numeric values for each separate column in the range. What I do wrong?

```
  function countNutrients(){
  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastcol = sh.getLastColumn(); //Get last column
  var lastcolval = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastcol).getValues();
  var lastrowval = sh.getRange("C1:C").getValues(); //Trick to get last row
  var lastrow = lastrowval.filter(String).length;   //
  var sumvalues = sh.getRange(2, 14, lastrow, lastcol).getValues();
    (typeof sumvalues === 'number' ? "" : sumvalues);
    Logger.log(sumvalues);
    for (var j = 13; j < lastcolval.length ; j++) {
       var sumcolumnval = sh.getRange(2, [j], lastrow);
       var sum = 0;
       for (var i in sumcolumnval[0]) {
       var sum = sumvalues[0][i] + sum;
     }
     return sum
     Logger.log(sum);
  }
  return sumcolumnval
  
}
```

Columns on the screenshot and 65 more

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eDB5bP37w4FGPFaDMhYvblGJZsTuNkhP/view?usp=sharing)

CSV example

Comment: provide screenshot of data  And expected output

Comment: Can you share a csv of your data?

Comment: Why not just use `=sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sum of Columns With a Script**

```
function sumOfCols() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet14');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var sum={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){sum[h]=0;});
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var v=rg.getValues();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){r.forEach(function(c,j){sum[hA[j]]+=c;});});
  var html='';
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s(sum): %s',h,sum[h]);});
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Column Sums")
}
```

Spreadsheet:

[image]

Output Dialog:

[image]

Data(csv):

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

**A function for your particular Application**

This will sum just the six columns that you selected

```
function countNutrients(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,14,1,6).getValues()[0];
  var sum={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){sum[h]=0;})
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,14,sh.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(!isNaN(c)) {
        sum[hA[j]]+=c;
      }
    });
  });
  var html="";
  var keys=Object.keys(sum);
  keys.forEach(function(k,i){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />sum[%s]=%s',k,sum[k]);
  })
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,'Sums of Cols N through S')
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works for me, but only for full numeric columns. Can you recommend how I can modify this code to ignore empty and not numeric values, please?

Comment: The last change will sum just the six columns that you selected on the image.

Comment: It's also helpful that you never leave spaces in the column headers when using them for object property names and you should probably also trim the column headers or make sure that you don't leave extra spaces and the beginning and end of the headers.  I spent several hours one evening because of spaces in the headers.

Comment: I just did something like what you appear to be doing.  I have a system for managing my Vitamin K, Oxalates, and Fat for all of my meals.  In also includes a webapp so that I can just take my phone in the kitchen to get the recipes for my meals.

Comment: Thank you for help. But still have an error "Object.keys is not a function". How can i fix it?

Comment: Sorry. getLastRow() takes last row of the table, but last row of data is 12. It's problem of all sheets what i have.
I use javascript trick through getting values and measure length.
Do you why the script don't recognize last row correctly?

Comment: Sorry. For so many questions. How to get all sums like 2-columns (Headers and sums) table at the new sheet?

Comment: The last row of a sheet is the last row that has any data on it and they always assumed a rectangular array of data with rows and column all the same lengths. I use a function like this if I just want the height of a column: `function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var v=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var s=0;
  var h=0;
  v.forEach(function(e,i){if(e==''){s++;}else{s=0;}h++;});
  return (h-s);
}`

Comment: Some people use the filter method for array at the end but the problem with that is if you have some datas that are blank it also removes them and then they get out of order.

Comment: The sum functions that I have given you are just starting points if you have a particularly unique data format then you will have to customize your solution to the format of your data.  In my case I usually think about the programming difficulty upfront and then try to provide the data format that is easy to implement in software.  For example, I take my vitals every day and I could have had a text box for every value.  Instead, I use one text box and put forward slashes between the data and just split on `/` and presto I have four separate datas.